# Trouble fetching multiple documents using find() in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to fetch more than one document that satisfies a particular criteria from a collection in my MongoDB database. When I use findOne(), it works perfectly fine and returns the first document that follows the criteria, but find() isn't returning all of the documents. I've checked a lot of websites and the documentation but still haven't found good examples of how it is done. This is the current syntax that I'm trying :

```
   db.collection('mycollection').find({someproperty : 
   somevalue}).then((docs)=>{
      // trying to do something with the returned documents 'docs'
   }
```

Also, I'd really prefer a non-mongoose solution, unless this is absolutely impossible using plain MongoDB. I know it's probably easier with mongoose but I want to know the MongoDB implementation.

Comment: how do you know its not returning all the documents?

Comment: try to use it without properties like this `{}` and see what it returns

Comment: I tried making an empty query - like just find(), but that also didn't work. It seems like incorrect syntax because my server responds with 503 service unavailable, but returns the first doc if its just findOne(). Really don't know what's going on :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Mongo Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) the `find` function returns a `cursor`.

> A cursor to the documents that match the query criteria. When the find() method “returns documents,” the method is actually returning a cursor to the documents.

I'm guessing you expect an array?  You need to use the `toArray` function, the docs for this are https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray

Unfortunately it's a callback, no promise implementation so you will need to put the promise in there yourself.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => db.collection('mycollection')
  .find({someproperty : somevalue})
  .toArray((err, documents) => resolve(documents)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not aware of the toArray function. Worked perfectly :)